# Draw horizontal line vertically centralized

Tags: pdftex

Ok, the title might be confusing. But the idea is pretty simple: I have this text that I would like to add a line on its side, but the line should be centralized vertically into the line, like so:

[image: Image example]

Any ideas on how to do it? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `xhfill` package provides tools to customise  `\hrulefill`:

```
\documentclass[svgnames]{article}
\usepackage{xhfill}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\textbf{Work Experience} \xrfill[0.5ex]{0.6pt}[Crimson]
\medskip

\lipsum{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Here are two ways of accomplishing your goal:

- `\raisebox{0.5ex}{<code for horizontal rule>}`
- `$\vcenter{\hbox{<code for horizontal rule>}}$`

The former raises the rule by `0.5ex`, where `ex` is the font's so-called x-height. The latter places the rule centered on the math axis. (In case you're wondering where the math-axis is located: In math mode, the `-` (minus) symbol is placed on the math axis, while the `=` symbol is centered vertically on it.)

The output of the two methods is fairly similar as long as the horizontal rule isn't too thick. In the following screenshot, the length and width of the rules is set to `6em` and `0.4pt`, respectively. You're obviously free to choose other values.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\textbf{Experience} \raisebox{0.5ex}{\rule{6em}{0.4pt}} $\vcenter{\hbox{\rule{6em}{0.4pt}}}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Any idea where I should go to create something that would make the bar automatically fill the whole line?

Comment: @LuizPedroFranciscattoGuerra - Does `\raisebox{-0.5ex}{\textbf{Experience}} \hrulefill` work for you? (You'll probably have to adjust the vertical spacing around this line. Just what the needed adjustment is will depend on what's on the page -- about which you haven't told us much so far...)

Answer (score 7):

Following [an answer to my past question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/457841/2288)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    Work Experience $\vcenter{\hbox{\begin{tikzpicture}\draw[-]  (0,0) -- ++(10mm,0);\end{tikzpicture}}}$
\end{document}
```